# Interfacing to Arduino over Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

How can I connect an iOS device to an Arduino device over Bluetooth?

I have a hardware device I would like to control with my phone.

Does it make a difference if the hardware is a commercial product and I provide the app via the app store?

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer for you on our sister site.

[Connect an iPhone to Arduino over Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537332/2241562)

> There are several ways to connect Bluetooth LE devices to the Arduino.
>   One I've used is the RedBearLabs BLE Shield.